# JSF Datatable - how to select row on button push in row

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I would like a button in a Primefaces DataTable row to show a dialog showing more information about the object in the row. When I click anywhere in the row not in the button, the row is selected. However, when I press the button, the row is not selected. How may I make the row that the button is in the selected row?

This example from the Primefaces showcase sets selectedCar in the backing bean and displays a dialog containing data from the row on clicking a button in the row but leaves the row unselected:

```
<p:dataTable id="basicDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars1}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Basic
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
         <p:commandButton update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

.. and this example from the same page selects a row in the table and the backing bean but an subsequent button click to display a dialog:

```
<p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars2}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCar}" rowKey="#{car.id}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Single with Row Click
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:carDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

I'm looking for a graceful solution where you can click any of multiple buttons in a row and select the row at the same time. Here's a use case where multiple buttons are useful - the data for the row contains two richtext fields of arbitrary size which are not easily shown in the table:
[image: Example datatable]

Comment: Can you add some code and image how you want to show dialog and select data table.

Comment: You can select the row by calling client side api function selectRow(r, silent) on click.

Comment: Is it important to **select** the row, or just to **show** the data on button click without selecting the row?

Comment: Strictly speaking I only need to show the data, really, for editing and writing back to the database, but I need the actual object displayed in the row for its ID so I know what record to update, and it does seem a better user experience for the row to be selected as well. I well show the code as soon as I can get around to it.

Comment: So what about using the var element of PrimeFaces dataTabe? `<p:dataTable var="current" ... >` and reference this inside the commandButton like `<p:commandButton ... actionListener="#{current}" ...>` Should behave the same when using dialog ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `var` value of the primefaces dataTable attribute, to create a commandLink (or button) inside each row of the dataTable:

1. If the commandLink is clicked, an actionListener is invoked and sets the rows object as the **selectedElement** inside the dataTableDialog bean.
2. Once the ajax request as finished successfully, the **update** attribute of the commandLink forces the dialog to request the current data from the bean.
3. Now the JavaScript code of the oncomplete attribute shows up the dialog.

   Take a look at the actionListener of the commandLink.

The rows object is stored inside member variable `selectedElement`. The data of this selected element is shown by the dialog.

Here you've got a nearly complete example:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" id="dialog">
      <h:outputText value="#{dataTableDialog.selectedElement.key} / #{dataTableDialog.selectedElement.val}" />
    </p:dialog>

    <p:dataTable
        var="cur"
        tableStyle="width: auto !important;"
        value="#{dataTableDialog.elements}">

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{cur.key}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{cur.val}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column>
            <p:commandLink
                value="Read more ..."
                actionListener="#{dataTableDialog.setSelectedElement(cur)}"
                update="form:dialog"
                oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The bean:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

    @javax.inject.Named
    @javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
    public class DataTableDialog implements Serializable {

    private List<Data>  elements;
    private Data        selectedElement;

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
        elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add(new Data("Elem 1 Key", "Elem 1 Value"));
        elements.add(new Data("Elem 2 Key", "Elem 2 Value"));
      }

      public List<Data> getElements() {
        return elements;
      }

      public Data getSelectedElement() {
        return selectedElement;
      }

      public void setSelectedElement(Data selectedElement) {
        this.selectedElement = selectedElement;
      }
    }
```

The data class:

```
public class Data implements Serializable {

    private String  key, val; // +getter/+setter

    public Data(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to look at this more closely - thanks - but at a glance I think it sets the selectedElement in the bean but does not select the row in the display, so the bean and the DataTable are out of sync. It would be possible to get the DataTable as a UIComponent in the bean and call selectRow() on it but since this is display logic it seems the wrong place to do it. I think I like @Ashish Mathew's answer better and I need to try it but I know I did once before and for some reason it did not work the way I expected. More later, and thank you.

Comment: "cur" references the object for each row. The example provides a two rows dataTable, clicking on "read more" shows the data of the row element inside a model dialog. Give it a try ... ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for your contributions on this question, but your answers do not address the original question of how to select the row in the datatable. What I'm looking for is a combination of what is shown in the Primefaces Showcase for Datatable Selection for "Basic" (click a button in the row) and "Single with Row Click". I want to click a button to bring up a dialog AND have the row for that button selected in the display when the dialog closes.

Comment: The "Basic" example shows how to set the selectedCar in the backing bean and bring up a dialog for that row when a button is clicked, but no row is selected in the datatable. The "Single with Row Click" example selects the row in the datatable AND the backing bean but does not bring up a dialog of the user's choosing, such as a delete or edit dialog.

Comment: I want to supply the user with multiple buttons in the row to a) bring up a dialog which displays richtext info than cannot be shown in the table, b) bring up an edit dialog to add comments on the row data, or c) edit rich text details for the row that cannot be shown in the table, and have the row selected after submission of edits.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the [primefaces show case](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) for dataTable *Selection*:

if it is an option to ommit the button, this example opens a dialog on row click, including row selection.

- add an ID to your DataModel
- add the attributes *selection*, *selectionMode* and *rowKey* to the dataTable
- insert `<p:ajax ... />` tag inside dataTable to show the dialog on rowSelectEvent

The facelet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
  <h:form id="form">
    <p:dialog
      widgetVar="elementDialog" modal="true">
      <p:outputPanel id="elementDetail">
        <p:panelGrid
          columns="2"
          rendered="#{not empty bean.selectedElement}"
          columnClasses="label,value">
          <h:outputText value="Key: #{bean.selectedElement.key}" />
          <h:outputText value="Val: #{bean.selectedElement.val}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
       </p:outputPanel>
      </p:dialog>

      <p:dataTable
        var="element"
        value="#{bean.elements}"
        selection="#{bean.selectedElement}"
        selectionMode="single"
        rowKey="#{element.id}"
        tableStyle="width: auto !important;">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="PF('elementDialog').show();" />

        <p:column headerText="Key">#{element.key}"</p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Val">#{element.val}"</p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

```html
<p:dataTable
  var="element"
  value="#{bean.elements}"
  selection="#{bean.selectedElement}"
  selectionMode="single"
  rowKey="#{element.id}"
  tableStyle="width: auto !important;">

  <p:ajax
    event="rowSelect"
    oncomplete="PF('elementDialog').show();" />

...
</p:dataTable>
```

The Data class:

```html
public class Data implements Serializable {

 private int    id;        // + getter/setter
 private String key, val;  // + getter/setter

 public Data(int id, String key, String value) {
  super();
  this.setId(id);
  this.key = key;
  this.value = value;
 }

}
```

The bean:

```html
public class Bean implements Serializable {

 private List<Data> elements;        // + getter
 private Data       selectedElement; // + getter/setter

 @PostConstruct
 public void init() {
  elements = new ArrayList<>();
  elements.add(new Data(0, "Elem 1 Key", "Elem 1 Value"));
  elements.add(new Data(1, "Elem 2 Key", "Elem 2 Value"));
 }

}
```

Hopefully this example leads you to archive your goal ... ;)